# Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found . . . Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg

Tags: lvm

Recently I definitely left Windows 10 and now, I'm trying my first steps in Linux

This is my very first issue, wich came a few days ago.

. . . Starting PC and after decrypting SSD system drive

```
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found  
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg  
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning  
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while ...  
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2  
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning  
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

I have no more info besides what was previously described. Normal PC operation, with **no config** changes.

- Ubuntu 18.04.3
- CPU Ryzen 5 3600
- RAM 2x8 GB G.Skill Flarex 3200 MHz CL16
- MB  MSI MPG X570
- SSD NVMe M.2 Samsung 970 EVO Plus 500 GB
- GPU Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti

Comment: Your computer still works, correct?  Even with these notices?

Comment: Yes. Aparently works normal.

Comment: Do you receive an encrypted partition/drive prompt to unlock it at boot?  I'm assuming so based on "encrypted SSD".

Comment: Yes. It' s a regular Ubuntu 18.04.3 installation, with disk and Home encryption

Comment: I just read your answer. Thank you very much for helping. Cheers from Portugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: This answer comes from my first-hand experience with Debian and Ubuntu encrypted systems (mostly Debian Unstable and testing Lubuntu 19.04/19.10 during devel cycles), but **this is normal** if the system is encrypted and requires an on-boot password.

While I do not know the *exact* reason this happens, from what I can tell when you have an encrypted partition, it can't *read* the partition with `lvmetad` and such while its encrypted.  Once it's decrypted, it's able to use and recognize the volume group.  Why this is the case I do not know, but I'm fairly sure we can consider this behavior you're observing "Normal Behavior" as I have reproduced this on Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04, 19.10, and Debian Unstable.

---

Since my 2019 post, **I have confirmed this is Standard Behavior for any full disk encryption configuration**.

You probably should have installed using **Encrypted home directory** and not full disk encryption - full disk encryption will prevent boot until you put in the disk encryption passphrase.  No way around it, as it's doing what it's designed to do - prevent unauthorized access to the disk.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I am having that I posted my question for. Where is the answer to this? I have always had to enter the decryption password before normal boot will take place.

Comment: @JamesReece the answer is: **you cannot bypass this** - the encryption is there for a reason to *protect* others from accessing your system.  If you want a normal boot process that doesn't need a password on boot, you probably need to have chosen encrypted *home* directory instead of full disk encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of what LUKS and full disk encryption is utilized for. My issue was, (I've already reinstalled 18.04) that I had a drive that I have been using for 3 years just up and stop providing the little black box at the bottom of the screen to be able to enter the decryption passphrase into, after I installed a secondary hdd from another machine. I wanted to know how to get my drive back to bootable fashion so that I didn't have to reinstall, hence where got the error msg, Volume group “ubuntu-vg” not found . . . Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg. I wanted to know how to get the machine to give me back the prompt for entering the decryption passphrase so that it would boot as I set it up to do. I could never get that box back to be able to enter the passphrase. Go ahead and delete all of this after you've read it. I don't know how to send this kind of stuff to you directly, or at least let me know you've read it so I can delete it.